# An example to show that $\left(I \cap J\right)^{e} = I^{e} \cap J^{e} $ is not true in general.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of a commutative ring with identity $R$ and $I^{e}$ be the extension of the ideal to some other ideal of another ring.

I have already proven that $\left(I \cap  J\right)^{e} \subset I^{e} \cap J^{e}$ and I am trying to look for a counterexample to show that the equality doesn't hold in general.

Any help finding this example would be much appreciated!

Comment: $R = \mathbb Z$, $I = J = 7R$, $(I \cap J)^e = I$, $I^e = J^e = R$ unless I did not understand your definition of extension.

Comment: Thank you very much! My definition for extension is $I^{e} =\{\displaystyle\sum sf(i): s \in S, i \in I\}$ where $f:R\rightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism between conmutative rings with identity.

Comment: Hello again @R.Suwalski, I was wondering how did you get this result for your example, I may be doing something wrong but when I try it out I get that in this case  $(I\cap J)^e=I^e\cap J^e$

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong, thank you very much @R.Suwalski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $k[t,s] \to k[x^2,x^3]$ for a field $k$, where $t,s,x$ are formal variables and we send $t\mapsto x^2$ and $s\mapsto x^3$ and extend $k$-linearly. For $I=(t), J=(s)$, we get $I \cap J=(ts)$ $I^e=(x^2), J^e=(x^3)$ and $(I\cap J)^e=(x^5)$.
Now what is $I^e\cap J^e=(x^2)\cap (x^3)$ in $k[x^2,x^3]$?
One might think that it is $(x^5)$, but it's actually larger: $x^6$ is a multiple of both $x^2$ and $x^3$, but not of $x^5$, as $x\notin k[x^2,x^3]$.

This strange behavior, that the intersection of two principal is principal in one ring, but not in the other ring is  a reflection of the fact that in $k[t,s]$ the elements $t$ and $s$ have a least common multiple, but the elements $x^2,x^3\in k[x^2,x^3]$ have not.

Here's another (perhaps simpler) example in which all ideals are principal, but the equality is still strict:
Consider the ring homomorphism $\Bbb Z[x,y] \to \Bbb Z$ that sends $x\mapsto 4$ and $x\mapsto 6$, then for $I=(x)$ and $J=(y)$ we get $I\cap J = (xy)$ and $I^e=(4)$, $J^e=(6)$ $(I\cap J)^e=(24)$, $I^e\cap J^e=(4) \cap (6) = (12)$.
One can of course replace $4$ and $6$ by any pair of non-zero integers which are not coprime (you can even take the same integer twice).

Comment: I assume you meant that you send $s\rightarrow x^3$

Comment: @CarlosSeda yes, of course, thanks, I fixed it.